# Bash script using wget to clone a website

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to create a bash script to clone a website, by modified the wget command found on [here](https://gist.github.com/mikecrittenden/fe02c59fed1aeebd0a9697cf7e9f5c0c).

This is what I have so far, but I'm having problems parsing the URL correctly:

```
URL=$1
DOMAIN=`echo $URL | sed -e 's/[^/]*\/\/\([^@]*@\)\?\([^:/]*\).*/\2/'`
echo $DOMAIN

wget \
     --recursive \ # Download the whole site.
     --page-requisites \ # Get all assets/elements (CSS/JS/images).
     --adjust-extension \ # Save files with .html on the end.
     --span-hosts \ # Include necessary assets from offsite as well.
     --convert-links \ # Update links to still work in the static version.
     --restrict-file-names=windows \ # Modify filenames to work in Windows as well.
     --domains $DOMAIN \ # Do not follow links outside this domain.
     --no-parent \ # Don't follow links outside the directory you pass in.
         $URL # The URL to download
```

The problem seems to be determining the domain from the URL.

This is the result when I try to clone a web page:

```
./clone_website.sh https://www.elliman.com/newyork/sales/detail/612-l-566-14_h344874/5-paumanok-road-water-mill-ny-11976
www.elliman.com
--2021-01-26 11:06:11--  http://%20/
Resolving   ( )... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘ ’
--2021-01-26 11:06:11--  http://download/
Resolving download (download)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘download’
--2021-01-26 11:06:11--  http://the/
Resolving the (the)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘the’
--2021-01-26 11:06:11--  http://whole/
Resolving whole (whole)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘whole’
--2021-01-26 11:06:11--  http://site./
Resolving site. (site.)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘site.’
./clone_website.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./clone_website.sh: line 7: `     --page-requisites \ # Get all assets/elements (CSS/JS/images).'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you show us what URL is before and after running your amendments?

Comment: what is the question? How do you want to fix *what*?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Question updated to reflect this

Comment: @umläute Question updated to show error messages. That should clarify what I want to fix

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli https://shellcheck.net is your friend.

Comment: `\ # Download the whole site.` Are the comments part of the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` has to be **the last character** on a line. Comments are not allowed after it. You want:

```
wget \
     --recursive \
     --page-requisites \
     --adjust-extension \
     --span-hosts \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains "$DOMAIN" \
     --no-parent \
         "$URL" # The URL to download This comment is fine
```

Your script is executing:

```
wget --recursive ' #' Download the whole site.

--page-requisites ' #' Get all assets/elements (CSS/JS/images).
                                                             ^^ - syntax error

etc.
```

And `wget` tries to download sites named `http:// #/` and `http://Download/` etc...

Remember to quote variable expansions to disable filename expansion and word splitting (and in case of urls, quote arguments to disable `&` subshell creation in the background). Use bash arrays for easier management in scripts:

```
runme=(
     wget # yay bash array - you can comment and no need for '\'
     --recursive # another comment
     --page-requisites # to this and that
     --adjust-extension
     --span-hosts
     --convert-links
     --restrict-file-names=windows
     --domains "$DOMAIN"
     --no-parent 
     "$URL" # The URL to download This comment is fine
)
"${runme[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
# replace the double-slash between protocol and domain with `%`:
DOMAIN_WITH_PROTOCOL=${URL/\/\//%}
# strip away all the path components
DOMAIN_WITH_PROTOCOL=${DOMAIN_WITH_PROTOCOL%%/*}
# replace the `%` (that we used to delimit protocol from domain) back to `//`
DOMAIN_WITH_PROTOCOL=${DOMAIN_WITH_PROTOCOL/\%///}
```

or just go for the domain and the protocol in separate steps, which takes one more step, but I find it easier to follow:

```sh
# overything before the first `://` is the protocol
proto=${URL%%://*}
# strip away the protocol, which gives us <domain>+<path>
domain=${URL#*://}
# strip the path from the domain:
domain=${domain%%/*}
# and reassemble protocol+domain:
DOMAIN_WITH_PROTOCOL="${proto://${domain}"
```